# What non-negative linear models are supported/planned in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, linear-regression, scikit-learn

Scikit-learn offers a large variety of useful linear models. However, I am working on a problem which is linear with non-negativity constraints (i.e. solution variables should be non-negative).

I would like to use scikit-learn, but the only function I saw that can support currently non-negativity is Lasso(), via the 'positive=true' flag. LassoCV() or lasso_path() don't support non-negativity.

Are there other non-negative linear models available in scikit-learn? Are there plans to include these in the near future?

Comment: There are no plans to include much new in scikit-learn; the dev team is discussing a feature freeze so that a 1.0 can be released in the near future.

Comment: Propagating the `positive=True` constructor parameter to `LassoCV` and `lasso_path` would still be accepted as a PR I think. It does not add much complexity to the existing code base as `LassoCV` and `lasso_path` are wrappers for `Lasso`.

Comment: anyone want to turn one of these into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current stable version of scikit-learn supports the `positive` kwarg in `LassoCV` and `lasso_path` (though the latter isn't mentioned in the docstring, it seems). Example of nonnegative `lasso_path` usage: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_coordinate_descent_path.py

The `ElasticNet` and associated CV-versions also support a nonnegative option.

Comment: oddly enough I get positive coefficients with `positive=True` in LassoCV, but some of by `predict()` values are still negative.. (and there are no negative input values..) weird.

Comment: What about the `intercept_` value?